# why the limit of this f(x) when x approach infinity is equal to infinity?

Tags: limits

why the limit of this f(x) when x approach infinity is equal to infinity?:

$$ \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x^2 + 4x + 5}{x-1}$$

$$ \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{1 + \frac{4}{x} + \frac{5}{x^2}}{\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x^2}} = \infty  $$

I know that all the fraction with X be denominator is equal to Zero but is that mean at the end the $ \lim_{x\to \infty} = \frac{1}{0}$ why it is equal to $ \infty $ ?

Comment: $\lfloor a \rfloor >a-1$ and the interior fraction also goes to $\infty$ so the limit is $\infty$  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{x^2+4x+5}{x-1}\right)=$$

---

The leading term in the denominator of $\frac{x^2+4x+5}{x-1}$ is $x$.

So divide the numerator and denominator by this:

---

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{x+4+\frac{5}{x}}{1-\frac{1}{x}}\right)=$$

---

The expressions $\frac{5}{x}$ and $\frac{1}{x}$ both tend to zero as $x$ approaches $\infty$:

---

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{x+4+0}{1-0}\right)=$$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{x+4}{1}\right)=$$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(x+4\right)=$$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}x=\infty$$

Comment: Thank you for your great answer, I saw in the video that it divide the top and the bottom part with x^2. Can you please also explain the process in case of divide with x^2 why it becomes infinity?

Comment: @user3270418 You've to look to the leading term, and that is in this case $x$ not $x^2$!

Answer (score -1):

i dont think limit can end with 1/0 = infinity as the answer tough.

heres my approach :

instead divide it by $x^2$  divide it by $x$ instead.

so it will be $\frac{(x+4+\frac{5}{x})}{x-1} $

since $\lim _{x\to infinity} \frac{5}{x}  $ and $\lim _{x\to infinity} \frac{-1}{x}  $ are 0 .

it leaves use with $\lim _{x\to infinity} x+4  $ which is equal to infinity